# getUserLabelByName with mails same subject

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I have this script:

```
 var label   = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Pendiente");//  
 var threads = label.getThreads(0, 30);//  
 var total   = threads.length;//
```

In my inbox, i have 3 mails with same subject with label="Pendiente".

But, the "total" value is 1. How can i get the 3 mails?

Thanks!

Comment: Three emails in a single thread? or three emails in three different threads?

Comment: I have 3 mails with same subject, from same person (FROM), in a single thread.

Comment: like this: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5z4ShedRkhLQWlST2RYMU5PalE

Answer (score 0):

Use getMessagesForThread to get mails

```
     var label   = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("test");//  
     var threads = label.getThreads(0, 30);// 
     var mails = GmailApp.getMessagesForThread(threads[0]);
     var total   = mails.length;//
```